# Reuse my old Depth-First Tree for a bigger depth while searching the longest path

Tags: c#, tree

I'm looking for the longest-path trough a map in a game which is turn based. I got 1s computation time and need to move at that point.

Right now I'm generating the tree every move again.

Is it possible to use my old tree and stack (in which I store the nodes yet to be visited) to get a bigger depth and thus a better result?

For now my SearchClass is based on a Interface, thus changing the return-type and the input-variables of my function is a lot of work. Is there an easy solution for my problem?

Comment: Longest path? What prevents you from making a longer path by retracing your steps? Move limit? Only visit each square once? Other?

Comment: Thats not the problem. 

At my turn I have 1s and after 900ms I'll likely have a tree of possible paths which is not complete. But I need to make a move and so I pick the one with the highed depth. 

So if it's my turn again, I would like to reuse my old generated tree (replacing it with the node I selected). 

If I would be able to do this, I could generate a more complete tree with the help of my old results.

Answer (score 0):

If your map is static and not overly large, you could generate your tree in advance.

For each node, calculate the longest path to every other node on the map then store the path and its length against the original node. That way, you no longer need to compute paths during program execution; you only need to use the pre-computed longest path from your current node to your chosen destination.

Answer (score 0):

Can you probably make your (Player's) tree static? Or if you are the only player, you could make it a global variable for the whole program on player's-side, but that depends on many things, that you did not share with us. I would still suggest you to have a look at MCTS:  [Wikipedia description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte-Carlo_tree_search) and [Here, it has sample code](http://mcts.ai/).

With MCTS the idea is simple: You compute all your 900ms, then make a player's move to the node, that has the highest winning-probability. If you can persist the tree as a global or static ( or both :D ) variable, the first thing, that you do at the begining of the next turn (or the next computation) is to get rid of all parts of the previous tree, that you can not access any more - because you are not at position `[0][0]`, but at position lets say `[1][3]` ... so that shrinks the tree-size for you, which is good. So what you have to do is to replace the original tree with a new tree, which starts with the node, that you are at the moment standing on. Good thing is, you have some values precomputed, now it depends on your implementation, how you want the nodes to be explored and/or probability-updated. But as the game goes on, the program should have enough data, that it can guarrant it a very high winning probability.

This approach is exceptionally good, because it does not compute the probabilities of the steps you do not take, when known, you are not going to take them (this is a thing you did not mention in your approach and I find it a necessity, so that's why I responded).

*Excuse any failures, I'm gonna specify/update/correct things upon request.*
*And all the things you are doing seem to meet some pattern of university-delivery, [see for example](https://cw.felk.cvut.cz/wiki/courses/a4b99rph/cviceni/reversi/start), if this is not your case, you could pretty well inspire there. If you have to meet some school-delivery, make sure you do not discuss too much into detail and/or do not ask for technical-implementation help.*

Comment: Boy, oh boy, oh boy, ... the topic is 4years old, the answer by JimmyTheOne propagated it to the very top, now I think its a little too late.